# How to avoid gap after merging two objects

Tags: mesh, objects, bevel

I tried to merge two objects A and B, before merging, I use the snap tool to snap each other perfectly along the edges as shown in the screen shot, After merging, the A and B become one object, then I selected them all by hitting "A", then beveling, I found the "Green X" area are beveled which I don't want to have, what should I do to make this face become one piece so there doesn't have any bevel in between?

[image: Two objects A and B before snapping]

[image: Snapping A to B]

[image: Ctrl+J to merge to a single object]

[image: After bevel]

Comment: For your own benefit you may want to put one or more images which shows your problem more fully.  The choice is yours. That image alone does not tell me much .. although it may tell everyone else much.  I do not see a bevel in that particular image.  Of course vertices can be added, deleted, updated  to get the mesh you want.

Comment: Any edge can be beveled.  Selecting all and using the bevel operation will not always get you your desired result.  Consider selecting less than all and beveling.

Comment: I put some details in it thanks

Comment: Edge can be beveled, but I have already joined the two objects at the green X edge, then why it is still an edge, it should be a single face

Comment: Better images. Although I cannot tell if your meshes are flat like a plane or 3D like cube. Please see a tutorial on loop cut and extrusion

Comment: When you start using Blender you might do yourself a favor and try to comply with Blender as it currently works.    This means seeing only a few of  the  hundreds of possibilities as time goes by.  Time consuming process.  Blender determines vertices, edges, and faces.  Casual inspection does not.  So Blender may not agree with your statements about [should].  Many times it is a situation of .. How can I work with Blender ... with all the Rules of Blender.  I suggest a tutorial series ... on noonoob ... maybe 20 episodes of 6 minutes on average.

Comment: Edges in the same mesh .. even close together .. may be identified as different faces by Blender.  Through time and tutorials this may become clearer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Left White Mesh. A Cube with loop cuts and one face [extruded] in the z direction.  Thus having the edges you might need to control bevel operation.  Next 2nd White Mesh Selected. Edges selected and the bevel operator used.   These meshes are intended as crude facsimiles of yours.

At this time we think having a fresh start is easier than [join] operator.  Or at least equivalent.

Possible option. 3rd from left Blue image. Faces selected and [Face Dissolve] operator used for a ngon, on both sides. Yellow image on right. Inset faces.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but this still doesn't address my problem, after a whole day's searching on the net I found an alternative solution, using "intersect/knife tool"

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an alternative solution for this case, using Intersect/Knife tool to address this situation, follow the steps:

1.Select all meshes on both object

2.Ctrl+F and select Intersect/Knife

3.The edges overlapped with each other will have cuts automatically generated for each vertices(vertices sit on the edge, because the two objects were edge snapped before)

4.Dissolve limited, because the vertices on object A will overlapped with the cuts on the edge.

Then it's done.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select object A
2. Go to *Modifier* and choose *Boolean*
3. Choose *Union*
4. Select B as an object
5. Done

[image]
[image]